# Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

Tags: 8

I am trying to download content in pdf.

I have done composer require mpdf/mpdf

Then in my code I have used the following:

```
use \Mpdf\Mpdf;

$mpdf = new Mpdf();

$filename = 'file.pdf';

$mpdf->Output($filename, 'D');
```

But I am getting error Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found in Drupal. Following some blogs I have tried using

```
$mpdf = new mPDF()
```

But the error still persists. Please help.

Comment: Where have you done the `composer require`? Is your site Composer managed? The leading backslash can be removed from the `use` statement. Where exactly are you having that code placed right now? Please **update your question** in a way that this becomes a reproducible problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was not running composer require mpdf/mpdf in the root directory. Now it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not running composer require mpdf/mpdf in the Drupal root directory. Hence the error.
Now it is resolved.